# How does a function influence an induced homomorphism?

Tags: algebraic-topology

Let T be continuous and surjective from X to Y. Is the induced homomorphism $T_*$ surjective? Does injectivity of T imply injectivity of $T_*$?

I have a feeling that this is trivial to answer and that I'm just not seeing it.

Comment: What does $T_*$ mean here ?

Comment: $T_*$ is the Induced homomorphism from $(X, x_0)$ to (Y, Tx_0)$.

Comment: But what does "injectivity" or"surjectivity" means for you for morphisms of pointed spaces ?

Answer (score 0):

Neither of these hold. Consider the standard covering of $S^1$ by $\mathbb R$ given by $x \mapsto (\cos(x),\sin(x))$. This is surjective, but on fundamental groups it is given by the inclusion of the trivial subgroup in $\mathbb Z$. For the other case, consider the inclusion $S^1 \to \mathbb R^2$; this is injective, but on fundamental groups this gives the unique homomorphism from $\mathbb Z$ to the trivial group.

Comment: Wouldn't the inclusion mapping (for the second case) be injective but not surjective?

Comment: I should've rephrased my question earlier. What if, in addition to T being surjective, we have that T is injective?

Comment: True, so that is a counterexample to `$T$ injective $\implies$ $T_*$ injective".

Comment: If $T$ is both surjective and injective, we still do not get surjectivity; consider the restriction of the first example to $[0,2\pi)$. I think we don't get injectivity either, but I think the example is more artificial.

Comment: Actually, the identity $S^1 \to S^1$, where the first copy has the usual topology and the second copy has the indiscrete topology shows that we do not get injectivity either.